# Color Image FFT Methods

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft

I'm practicing FFT algorithm recently.

I'm just wondering why I cannot use HSV's V channel or YCbCr's Y channel to do color image FFT?
The result of these two method looks like the colors overflow the contours of the image.

So the only way to do this is to compute R, G, B channel separately?

Comment: You can certainly do FFT on encoding that uses channels other than R, G and B. In fact, to the FFT it's utterly irrelevant what sort of color channel the data represents (or even whether it represents color data at all).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Technically, you're right. The FFT works on a series of numbers. But the interpretation of those numbers may become meaningless. In particular, the magnitude of the FFT results can usually be interpreted as energies at spatial freqencies - definitely so for the R,G,B channels as well as for the V channel. But the FFT of the H channel is troublesome.

Comment: @KKyang: Can you add examples? In the frequency domain, there are no contours of the image. Contours imply a compact support in the spatial domain, which means there isn't a compact support in the frequency domain.

Comment: @MSalters: Quite true. Typically you want to separate into channels that are each as independent from the others as possible, such as something like YUV, then compress those (but if you care about efficiency, you also usually use DCT instead of FFT).